# Performance issue in .NET remoting

Tags: c#, .net

I can't understand why this strange behavior when I call the method remotely is expensive.

I have observed a performance issue when my object method called remotely compared to when it's called within the same process.  To confess, I don't have good understanding of .NET remoting technology. Yes I have read few articles, but I haven't understood how to resolve this specific problem.

I had supportive data from ants performance profiler which clearly shows call to `DisconnectFromPublisher()-> UnsubscribeAll();` is expensive.

I have modified my code to simplify the problem. The skeleton is as follows. Give me some pointers why the method is expensive when it's invoked remotely.

```
/// <summary>
/// A data object that holds callback information.
/// </summary>
public class CallbackDelegate
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The delegate that should be invoked to perform the callback.
    /// </summary>
    public SampleDelegate SampleDelegate;

    /// <summary>
    /// The client control that has the callback method.
    /// This value can be null.
    /// </summary>
    public Control ClientControl;

    /// <summary>
    /// a unique key is used to identify each callback info
    /// </summary>
    public Guid CallbackDelegateKey;
}

/// <summary>
/// A helper class that allows clients to receive notification messages
/// by subscribing to topics.
/// </summary>
public class Subscriber : MarshalByRefObject
{
    #if DEBUG
    // Allows exceptions to be injected during unit testing of debug builds.
    private string _testCase = null;
    #endif

    /// <summary>
    /// The publisher to which this subscriber is connected.
    /// </summary>
    public Publisher Publisher
    {
        get { return _publisher; }
    }
    private Publisher _publisher;


    /// <summary>
    /// Notification Dispatcher
    /// </summary>
    private Dispatcher _Dispatcher = new Dispatcher();

    private Dictionary<string, List<CallbackDelegate>> _clientCallbacks = new Dictionary<string, List<CallbackDelegate>>();

    /// <summary>
    /// sync object for client callbacks list
    /// </summary>
    private object _syncObj = new object();
    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor for a notification subscriber.
    /// </summary>
    public Subscriber()
    {
        _Dispatcher.Notify += new EventHandler<NotificationEventArgs>                                   (_Dispatcher_Notify);
    }

    public void Unsubscribe(string topicName)
    {
        // Check the method parameter.
        if (topicName == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }
        try
        {
            lock (_syncObj)
            {
                // Remove the client callback (indexed by topic name).
                _clientCallbacks.Remove(topicName);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Unsubscribes from all topics that this object has susbcribed to.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="PublisherAccessException">An error occurred while         unsubscribing from a topic.</exception>
    public void UnsubscribeAll()
    {
        lock (_syncObj)
        {
            // Access the topic names before modifying the list (with Unsubscribe).
            Queue<string> topics = new Queue<string>();
            foreach (string name in _clientCallbacks.Keys)
            {
                topics.Enqueue(name);
            }

            //For each topic name...
            while (topics.Count > 0)
            {
                string topicName = topics.Dequeue();

                // Unsubscribe the topic.
                Unsubscribe(topicName);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Disconnects from the publisher.
    /// This subscriber will no longer subscribe to any topics.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="PublisherAccessException">An error occurred while unsubscribing from a topic.</exception>
    public void DisconnectFromPublisher()
    {
        try
        {
            _Dispatcher.Stop();
            // Unsubscribe from all topic.
            UnsubscribeAll();
        }
        catch (PublisherAccessException)
        {
            throw;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new PublisherAccessException("An error occurred while disconnecting from the notification publisher.", ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            // Do not keep a reference to the publisher.
            _publisher = null;
            lock (_syncObj)
            {
                _clientCallbacks.Clear();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Both `Unsubscribe` and `UnsubscribeAll` acquire a lock on `_syncObj` so I would guess that is the source. To be honest I'm surprised this doesn't cause a deadlock in the first place since the calls to `Unsubscribe` are nested inside `UnsubscribeAll`.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel `lock` is recursive, so if the current thread already owns the lock, it can acquire it again.

Comment: I'm not sure there's enough code here to figure out the performance problem. Could you include the code that uses this?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, [Chapter 11 - Improving Remoting Performance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647782.aspx) looks promising. If not, maybe [remoting performance and inner workings of MarshalByRefObject](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/997996d0-c1e2-4eee-9d2d-d3d8ded671da/remoting-performance-and-inner-workings-of-marshalbyrefobject?forum=wcf) will help.

Next, a few observations/questions/ideas:

1. Why iterate through and Unsubscribe for each topic? Just clear the dictionary and be done with it.
2. You can [initialize a queue with an IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/69zckb8z.aspx), so don't iterate to enqueue items (especially because your code doesn't care in what order things are done).
3. Throwing exceptions is very expensive - is that happening in the remote case? In fact, `Remove` should only throw if the argument is null, and you're already checking for that, so try just removing the try/catch.
4. As mentioned before, your code doesn't care about the order of operations, which means that it is a perfect candidate for parallel processing. Why not use a [ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx) or similar data structure and do the operations in parallel?
5. Why are you using MarshalByRef? Do you know [how expensive is MarshalByRefObject compared to serialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6503380/how-expensive-is-using-marshalbyrefobject-compared-to-serialization)

None of these specifically address why the remote call is slow, but you should be able to try them and see if perf improves.